# Unable to access the server which i started in bash on windows?

Tags: httpserver

I have started a node server in bash on windows(ubuntu), but i cannot access it by browser.

**Project path:**

```
e:/file/express-server (real path of this project)
```

**How to start:**

1. open bash on windows
2. cd /mnt/e/file/express-server
3. npm start

**Result:**

the server has started, but i cannot access to it. If i start it in windows system, it's useful to access, Any problem of it? **Thank you**!

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, this Forum is for Developers by Developers, for general server help may visit https://superuser.com/